# Iphone Core Data Internal Inconsistency

Tags: iphone, core-data

This question has something to do with the question I posted here: [Iphone Core Data crashing on Save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230858/iphone-core-data-crashing-on-save)
however the error is different so I am making a new question. Now I get this error when trying to insert new objects into my managedObjectContext:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
 reason: '"MailMessage" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'
```

But clearly it is:

```
@interface MailMessage : NSManagedObject { ....
```

And when I run this code:

```
 NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[self.managedObjectContext
    persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel];

 NSEntityDescription *entity =[[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] 
    objectForKey:@"MailMessage"];

 NSManagedObject *newObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity 
    insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

It runs fine when I do not present an MFMailComposeViewController, but if I run this code in the

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller 
  didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
```

method, it throws the above error when creating the newObject variable.
The entity object when I use print object produces the following:

```
(<NSEntityDescription: 0x1202e0>) name MailMessage, managedObjectClassName MailMessage, 
   renamingIdentifier MailMessage, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {
```

in both cases, so I don't think the managedObjectContext is completely invalid. I have no idea why it would say MailMessage is not a subclass of NSManagedObject at that point, and not at the other.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to workaround this by creating the MailMessage object before presenting the modal view controller. Once the MailMessage object was already created, saving changes did not present a problem. A strange workaround and not addressing the actual problem as far as I know, but it works.

Answer (score 10):

Class MailMessage could be implemented in a library or somewhere else in the framework. As Objective C does not implement namespaces, one of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. Try giving your class a different name to quickly resolve the issue.

Comment: I never would've thought about that..... fixed everything right up... :) Thanks a million! :D
Though i have to admit, the new xCode 4 was really annoying when it came to changing the name... i had to create a new entity and copy all the attributes/connections... /:

Comment: Thanks a million. I was stuck in the problem for the whole day. I used an entity "Account", ... always get the the error. I fixed by change it to "XXXAccount".

Answer (score 4):

Look for a message like this from the debugger. It will confirm what Benjamin says.

Class MailMesssage is implemented in both `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message` and `/Users/home/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/FFFFFFFF-FFFF-0000-0000-AAAAAAAAAAA/Projects.app/Projects`. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: haven't tried it my self, but if it does, it deserves a thumbs up... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the Simulator or uninstalling the application from your device. Often the `NSInternalInconsistencyException` has to do with problems with changing the datamodel and the database not being updated accordingly.