# Core Data Exception coerceValueForKeyWithDescription

Tags: ios, swift, exception, core-data, uikit

I'm having trouble fixing a non-reproducible crash that's only appearing on a couple user devices. The exception is raised while changing the properties of a Core Data managed object, and then saving those changes. The users report that their changes are not persisted next time they open the app after the crash. Here is the crash log up to the binary images:

```swift
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,5
Process:             Pupl [25152]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E75455E2-43A9-4C5C-BEFF-3E64F5046322/Pupl.app/Pupl
Identifier:          com.kevinolmats.Pupl
Version:             285 (1.0.1)
AppStoreTools:       12A7402a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone12,5:14
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.kevinolmats.Pupl [1530]


Date/Time:           2020-10-25 09:57:57.2646 -0600
Launch Time:         2020-10-25 09:48:56.9577 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.0.1 (18A393)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.00.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1935665ac __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a75e042c objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreData                        0x19961a648 _PFManagedObject_coerceValueForKeyWithDescription + 2004 (NSManagedObject.m:0)
3   CoreData                        0x19961f6f4 _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 192 (NSManagedObject_Accessors.m:1412)
4   Pupl                            0x100d96cac specialized WeightCategoryEditorViewModel.init(course:color:context:) + 596 (WeightCategoryEditorViewModel.swift:30)
5   Pupl                            0x100d8d7a0 0x100d44000 + 300960
6   SwiftUI                         0x199ed30b0 partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in DefaultListButtonStyle.ListButton.body.getter + 28 (PrimitiveButtonStyle.swift:47)
7   SwiftUI                         0x199ddb9c4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   SwiftUI                         0x199e60e90 specialized closure #2 in PlatformItemList.containerSelectionBehavior.getter + 68 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   SwiftUI                         0x199efb3f8 ListCoreCoordinator.tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) + 908 (ListCore_PhoneTV.swift:1250)
10  SwiftUI                         0x199efb6e4 @objc ListCoreCoordinator.tableView(_:willBeginEditingRowAt:) + 136
11  UIKitCore                       0x1960860d0 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:isCellMultiSelect:] + 1064 (UITableView.m:8278)
12  UIKitCore                       0x196085c8c -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 112 (UITableView.m:8192)
13  UIKitCore                       0x196086438 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 272 (UITableView.m:8317)
14  UIKitCore                       0x19634b544 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 72 (_UIAfterCACommitQueue.m:122)
15  UIKitCore                       0x195e90400 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 300 (UIApplication.m:2924)
16  UIKitCore                       0x195e7f1bc _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 204 (UIApplication.m:2902)
17  UIKitCore                       0x195eb2648 _afterCACommitHandler + 80 (UIApplication.m:2958)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x1934e2444 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36 (CFRunLoop.c:1799)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x1934dc858 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 576 (CFRunLoop.c:1912)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x1934dce08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1056 (CFRunLoop.c:2953)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x1934dc4bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
22  GraphicsServices                0x1a9f61820 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
23  UIKitCore                       0x195e80734 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3270)
24  UIKitCore                       0x195e85e10 UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4739)
25  SwiftUI                         0x19a23d32c closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 112 (UIKitApp.swift:34)
26  SwiftUI                         0x19a23d2b8 runApp<A>(_:) + 220 (<compiler-generated>:0)
27  SwiftUI                         0x199db6b08 static App.main() + 140 (App.swift:113)
28  Pupl                            0x100d5311c $main + 56 (Assignment.swift:0)
29  Pupl                            0x100d5311c main + 68
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x1931a3e60 start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bf49798c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001daabfc74 pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1375)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019c668bb4 abort + 104 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a76dfe24 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a76d1434 demangling_terminate_handler() + 308 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a75e0710 _objc_terminate() + 132 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a76df2a8 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a76e2174 __cxa_rethrow + 148 (cxa_exception.cpp:617)
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a75e05ec objc_exception_rethrow + 44 (objc-exception.mm:604)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001934dc5a8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 836 (CFRunLoop.c:3257)
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a9f61820 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
11  UIKitCore                       0x0000000195e80734 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3270)
12  UIKitCore                       0x0000000195e85e10 UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4739)
13  SwiftUI                         0x000000019a23d32c closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 112 (UIKitApp.swift:34)
14  SwiftUI                         0x000000019a23d2b8 runApp<A>(_:) + 220 (<compiler-generated>:0)
15  SwiftUI                         0x0000000199db6b08 static App.main() + 140 (App.swift:113)
16  Pupl                            0x0000000100d5311c $main + 56 (Assignment.swift:0)
17  Pupl                            0x0000000100d5311c main + 68
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001931a3e60 start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000016f0bad10   x5: 0x000000016f0bb2c0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000700
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x0d58175f700a1725  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000046
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001010838c0  x18: 0x000000010b9b6d8c  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x00000001010839a0  x22: 0x0000000000000001  x23: 0x00000002835989d0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000eb1e31100  x27: 0x00000001e70b3000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016f0bb220   lr: 0x00000001daabfc74
    sp: 0x000000016f0bb200   pc: 0x00000001bf49798c cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Note the `WeightCategoryEditorViewModel.init` on frame 4. This is the frame that changes between crash logs, but the subsequent frames are the same. Here's the init for the `WeightCategoryEditorViewModel`:

```swift
/// Creates a new model which edits the given weight category.
init(weightCategory: WeightCategory, color: Color = .accentColor, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    self.context = context
    self.weightCategory = weightCategory
    self.accentColor = color
    self.isEditing = true
    self.name = weightCategory.name
    self.weight = String(format: "%.0f", weightCategory.weight)
}
```

Anyone know what my next steps should be?

Comment: Thread 0 crashed, there is nothing about Core Data in it.

Comment: I was just looking at the last exception backtrace. Looking now at thread 0, do you have any ideas as to what the issue might be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230858/iphone-core-data-crashing-on-save Here, someone suggested that it could happen because the managed context was saved, but the managed object was still being used, which could throw an exception because the reference to the object could get lost